# Why two pipelines created in WebGPU and both of them are multisampled，only one of them can be displayed？

Tags: webgpu

I'm using WebGPU to develop some GIS layers.When I use WebGPU to draw lines with MSAA(multisample), I found a strange problem:
here are two pipeline init functions:

```
//init func for layer ODLine
export async function initPipelineODLine(data, device, format, size, viewport, mvpbuffer) {

    let N = 60;

    const vertexArray = new Float32Array(data.area.length * 3)

    const colorArr = new Float32Array(data.color)

    data.area.forEach((point, i) => {
        vertexArray[i * 3] = lngLatToWorld(point)[0];
        vertexArray[i * 3 + 1] = lngLatToWorld(point)[1];
        vertexArray[i * 3 + 2] = 0;

    });


    const pipeline = await device.createRenderPipelineAsync({
        layout: 'auto',
        vertex: {
            module: device.createShaderModule({
                code: vertodline
            }),
            entryPoint: 'main',
            buffers: [{
                arrayStride: 3 * 4,
                attributes: [{
                    shaderLocation: 0,
                    offset: 0,
                    format: 'float32x3'
                }]
            },
            {
                arrayStride: 4 * 4,
                attributes: [{
                    shaderLocation: 1,
                    offset: 0,
                    format: 'float32x4'
                }]
            },
            ],
        },

        fragment: {
            module: device.createShaderModule({
                code: fragodline
            }),
            entryPoint: 'main',
            targets: [{ format }]
        },
        primitive: {
            topology: 'triangle-list',
            //cullMode: 'back'
        },
        depthStencil: {
            depthWriteEnabled: true,
            depthCompare: 'less',
            format: 'depth24plus',
        },
        multisample: {
            count: 4,
            alphaToCoverageEnabled: true
        }
    })
    // create depthTexture for renderPass
    const multiTexture =  device.createTexture({
        size,
        sampleCount: 4,
        format,
        usage: window.GPUTextureUsage.RENDER_ATTACHMENT,
    });

    const depthTexture = device.createTexture({
        size,
        sampleCount: 4,
        format: 'depth24plus',
        usage: window.GPUTextureUsage.RENDER_ATTACHMENT,
    });
    const depthView = depthTexture.createView()
    // create vertex buffer
    const vertexBuffer = device.createBuffer({
        size: vertexArray.byteLength, // vertex.length * 4
        usage: window.GPUBufferUsage.VERTEX | window.GPUBufferUsage.COPY_DST
    })
    const colorBuffer = device.createBuffer({
        size: colorArr.byteLength,
        usage: window.GPUBufferUsage.VERTEX | window.GPUBufferUsage.COPY_DST
    })

    device.queue.writeBuffer(vertexBuffer, 0, vertexArray)
    device.queue.writeBuffer(colorBuffer, 0, colorArr)

    // console.log(vertexBuffer, colorBuffer);

    // create a mvp matrix buffer


    // const mvpBuffer = device.createBuffer({
    //     size: mvp0.length * 4,
    //     usage: window.GPUBufferUsage.UNIFORM | window.GPUBufferUsage.COPY_DST
    // })
    const mvpBuffer = mvpbuffer

    // console.log(mvpMatrix);
    // console.log(mvp0);

    // device.queue.writeBuffer(mvpBuffer, 0, mvp0)
    // create a uniform group for Matrix
    const uniformGroup = device.createBindGroup({
        layout: pipeline.getBindGroupLayout(0),
        entries: [
            {
                binding: 0,
                resource: { buffer: mvpBuffer }
            },
        ]
    })
    // return all vars
    return { pipeline, vertexBuffer, colorBuffer, mvpBuffer, uniformGroup, depthTexture, depthView,multiTexture }
}
```

and another：

```
export async function initPipelineLine(data, device, format, size, viewport, mvpbuffer) {

    let N = 60;

    const vertexArray = new Float32Array(data.area.length * 3)

    const colorArr = new Float32Array(data.color)

    data.area.forEach((point, i) => {
        vertexArray[i * 3] = lngLatToWorld(point)[0];
        vertexArray[i * 3 + 1] = lngLatToWorld(point)[1];
        vertexArray[i * 3 + 2] = 0;

    });


    const pipeline = await device.createRenderPipelineAsync({
        layout: 'auto',
        vertex: {
            module: device.createShaderModule({
                code: vertpoint
            }),
            entryPoint: 'main',
            buffers: [{
                arrayStride: 3 * 4,
                attributes: [{
                    shaderLocation: 0,
                    offset: 0,
                    format: 'float32x3'
                }]
            },
            {
                arrayStride: 3 * 4,
                attributes: [{
                    shaderLocation: 1,
                    offset: 0,
                    format: 'float32x3'
                }]
            },
            ],
        },

        fragment: {
            module: device.createShaderModule({
                code: fragpoint
            }),
            entryPoint: 'main',
            targets: [{ format }]
        },
        primitive: {
            topology: 'triangle-list',
            //cullMode: 'back'
        },
        depthStencil: {
            depthWriteEnabled: true,
            depthCompare: 'less',
            format: 'depth24plus',
        },
        multisample: {
            count: 4,
            alphaToCoverageEnabled: true
        }
    })
    // create depthTexture for renderPass
    const multiTexture =  device.createTexture({
        size,
        sampleCount: 4,
        format,
        usage: window.GPUTextureUsage.RENDER_ATTACHMENT,
    });
    const depthTexture = device.createTexture({
        size,
        sampleCount: 4,
        format: 'depth24plus',
        usage: window.GPUTextureUsage.RENDER_ATTACHMENT,
    });
    const depthView = depthTexture.createView()
    // create vertex buffer
    const vertexBuffer = device.createBuffer({
        size: vertexArray.byteLength, // vertex.length * 4
        usage: window.GPUBufferUsage.VERTEX | window.GPUBufferUsage.COPY_DST
    })
    const colorBuffer = device.createBuffer({
        size: colorArr.byteLength,
        usage: window.GPUBufferUsage.VERTEX | window.GPUBufferUsage.COPY_DST
    })



    device.queue.writeBuffer(vertexBuffer, 0, vertexArray)
    device.queue.writeBuffer(colorBuffer, 0, colorArr)

    // console.log(vertexBuffer, colorBuffer);

    // create a mvp matrix buffer


    // const mvpBuffer = device.createBuffer({
    //     size: mvp0.length * 4,
    //     usage: window.GPUBufferUsage.UNIFORM | window.GPUBufferUsage.COPY_DST
    // })
    const mvpBuffer = mvpbuffer

    // console.log(mvpMatrix);
    // console.log(mvp0);

    // device.queue.writeBuffer(mvpBuffer, 0, mvp0)
    // create a uniform group for Matrix
    const uniformGroup = device.createBindGroup({
        layout: pipeline.getBindGroupLayout(0),
        entries: [
            {
                binding: 0,
                resource: { buffer: mvpBuffer }
            },
        ]
    })
    // return all vars
    return { pipeline, vertexBuffer, colorBuffer, mvpBuffer, uniformGroup, depthTexture, depthView, multiTexture }
}
```

then I draw these layers:

```
else if (data.type === 'bus') {
        pipelineObj[k] = await initPipelineLine(data, device, format, size, viewport, mvpbuffer)



        // device.queue.writeBuffer(pipelineObj[k].mvpBuffer, 0, mvp01)
        // readBuffer.unmap()
        // then draw

        async function drawall() {
          commandEncoderArc = await device.createCommandEncoder()
          passEncoderBus = commandEncoderArc.beginRenderPass({
            colorAttachments: [{
              // view:context.getCurrentTexture().createView(),
              view: pipelineObj[k].multiTexture.createView(),
              resolveTarget: context.getCurrentTexture().createView(),
              clearValue: [0, 0, 0, 0],
              loadOp: 'clear',
              storeOp: 'store'
            }],
            depthStencilAttachment: {
              view: pipelineObj[k].depthTexture.createView(),
              depthClearValue: 1.0,
              depthLoadOp: 'clear',
              depthStoreOp: 'store',
            },
          })
          passEncoderBus.setPipeline(pipelineObj[k].pipeline)
          // device.queue.writeBuffer(pipelineObj[k].tBuffer, 0, t1)
          setsome(data, device, context, pipelineObj[k], passEncoderBus, commandEncoderArc)
          draw(data, device, context, pipelineObj[k], passEncoderBus, commandEncoderArc)
          requestAnimationFrame(drawall)
        }
        drawall()
      }
      else if (data.type === 'odline') {
        pipelineObj[k] = await initPipelineODLine(data, device, format, size, viewport, mvpbuffer)
        // device.queue.writeBuffer(pipelineObj[k].mvpBuffer, 0, mvp01)
        // readBuffer.unmap()
        // then draw
        async function drawall() {
          commandEncoderArc = await device.createCommandEncoder()
          passEncoderODLine = commandEncoderArc.beginRenderPass({
            colorAttachments: [{
              // view:context.getCurrentTexture().createView(),
              view: pipelineObj[k].multiTexture.createView(),
              resolveTarget: context.getCurrentTexture().createView(),
              clearValue: [0, 0, 0, 0],
              loadOp: 'clear',
              storeOp: 'store'
            }],
            depthStencilAttachment: {
              view: pipelineObj[k].depthTexture.createView(),
              depthClearValue: 1.0,
              depthLoadOp: 'clear',
              depthStoreOp: 'store',
            },
          })
          passEncoderODLine.setPipeline(pipelineObj[k].pipeline)
          // device.queue.writeBuffer(pipelineObj[k].tBuffer, 0, t1)
          setsome(data, device, context, pipelineObj[k], passEncoderODLine, commandEncoderArc)
          draw(data, device, context, pipelineObj[k], passEncoderODLine, commandEncoderArc)
          requestAnimationFrame(drawall)
        }
        drawall()
      }
```

the problem is that when only one of these pipelines enabled MSAA, layers can be displayed correctly.
[one of these layers opens MSAA,multisample count of layerODline is 4 and multisample count of layerLine is 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdEYI.png)

But when both of them enables MSAA, only the last layer can be displayed.

[both of them opens MSAA, only layerLine can be displayed and layerODline is disappered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCJHQ.png)

I tried to change the depthTexture format but noffect.All of layers can be displayed correctly before enableing MSAA in two layers.

**ALSO THANK FOR THE COMMENT FROM @GMAN BUT IT DOS NOT WORK** I tried to change the loadOp to load , it not only does not work,but also seems like a disaster…

[what a disaster... more and more lines gathering on the screen and the odline layer also disappered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeNcC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have `loadOp: 'clear'` in both render passes. You only want to clear in the first render pass. You should set `loadOp` to `'load'` in render passes after the first one

Also, you only want to resolve in the last render pass, otherwise you're resolving extra times for no reason.

```css
html, body { margin: 0; height: 100% }
canvas { width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block; }

#fail {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 16pt;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
<div id="fail" style="display: none">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
  
<script type="module">
// WebGPU Cube
// from https://webgpufundamentals.org/webgpu/webgpu-cube.html


/* global GPUBufferUsage */
/* global GPUTextureUsage */

import {vec3, mat4} from 'https://webgpufundamentals.org/3rdparty/wgpu-matrix.module.js';

async function main() {
  const adapter = await navigator.gpu?.requestAdapter();
  const device = await adapter?.requestDevice();
  if (!device) {
    fail('need webgpu');
    return;
  }

  const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
  const context = canvas.getContext('webgpu');

  const presentationFormat = navigator.gpu.getPreferredCanvasFormat(adapter);
  const presentationSize = [300, 150];  // default canvas size

  context.configure({
    alphaMode: "opaque",
    format: presentationFormat,
    device,
  });

  const canvasInfo = {
    canvas,
    context,
    presentationSize,
    presentationFormat,
    // these are filled out in resizeToDisplaySize
    renderTarget: undefined,
    renderTargetView: undefined,
    depthTexture: undefined,
    depthTextureView: undefined,
    sampleCount: 4,  // can be 1 or 4
  };

  const shaderSrc = `
  struct VSUniforms {
    worldViewProjection: mat4x4<f32>,
    worldInverseTranspose: mat4x4<f32>,
  };
  @group(0) @binding(0) var<uniform> vsUniforms: VSUniforms;

  struct MyVSInput {
      @location(0) position: vec4<f32>,
      @location(1) normal: vec3<f32>,
      @location(2) texcoord: vec2<f32>,
  };

  struct MyVSOutput {
    @builtin(position) position: vec4<f32>,
    @location(0) normal: vec3<f32>,
    @location(1) texcoord: vec2<f32>,
  };

  @vertex
  fn myVSMain(v: MyVSInput) -> MyVSOutput {
    var vsOut: MyVSOutput;
    vsOut.position = vsUniforms.worldViewProjection * v.position;
    vsOut.normal = (vsUniforms.worldInverseTranspose * vec4<f32>(v.normal, 0.0)).xyz;
    vsOut.texcoord = v.texcoord;
    return vsOut;
  }

  struct FSUniforms {
    lightDirection: vec3<f32>,
  };

  @group(0) @binding(1) var<uniform> fsUniforms: FSUniforms;
  @group(0) @binding(2) var diffuseSampler: sampler;
  @group(0) @binding(3) var diffuseTexture: texture_2d<f32>;

  @fragment
  fn myFSMain(v: MyVSOutput) -> @location(0) vec4<f32> {
    var diffuseColor = textureSample(diffuseTexture, diffuseSampler, v.texcoord);
    var a_normal = normalize(v.normal);
    var l = dot(a_normal, fsUniforms.lightDirection) * 0.5 + 0.5;
    return vec4<f32>(diffuseColor.rgb * l, diffuseColor.a);
  }
  `;

  const shaderModule = device.createShaderModule({code: shaderSrc});

  function createBuffer(device, data, usage) {
    const buffer = device.createBuffer({
      size: data.byteLength,
      usage,
      mappedAtCreation: true,
    });
    const dst = new data.constructor(buffer.getMappedRange());
    dst.set(data);
    buffer.unmap();
    return buffer;
  }

  const positions = new Float32Array([1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]);
  const normals   = new Float32Array([1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1]);
  const texcoords = new Float32Array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]);
  const indices   = new Uint16Array([0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 16, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 20, 22, 23]);

  const positionBuffer = createBuffer(device, positions, GPUBufferUsage.VERTEX);
  const normalBuffer = createBuffer(device, normals, GPUBufferUsage.VERTEX);
  const texcoordBuffer = createBuffer(device, texcoords, GPUBufferUsage.VERTEX);
  const indicesBuffer = createBuffer(device, indices, GPUBufferUsage.INDEX);

  const tex = device.createTexture({
    size: [2, 2, 1],
    format: 'rgba8unorm',
    usage:
      GPUTextureUsage.TEXTURE_BINDING |
      GPUTextureUsage.COPY_DST,
  });
  device.queue.writeTexture(
      { texture: tex },
      new Uint8Array([
        255, 255, 128, 255,
        128, 255, 255, 255,
        255, 128, 255, 255,
        255, 128, 128, 255,
      ]),
      { bytesPerRow: 8, rowsPerImage: 2 },
      { width: 2, height: 2 },
  );

  const sampler = device.createSampler({
    magFilter: 'nearest',
    minFilter: 'nearest',
  });

  function createPipelineAndStuff(device) {
    const pipeline = device.createRenderPipeline({
      layout: 'auto',
      vertex: {
        module: shaderModule,
        entryPoint: 'myVSMain',
        buffers: [
          // position
          {
            arrayStride: 3 * 4, // 3 floats, 4 bytes each
            attributes: [
              {shaderLocation: 0, offset: 0, format: 'float32x3'},
            ],
          },
          // normals
          {
            arrayStride: 3 * 4, // 3 floats, 4 bytes each
            attributes: [
              {shaderLocation: 1, offset: 0, format: 'float32x3'},
            ],
          },
          // texcoords
          {
            arrayStride: 2 * 4, // 2 floats, 4 bytes each
            attributes: [
              {shaderLocation: 2, offset: 0, format: 'float32x2',},
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
      fragment: {
        module: shaderModule,
        entryPoint: 'myFSMain',
        targets: [
          {format: presentationFormat},
        ],
      },
      primitive: {
        topology: 'triangle-list',
        cullMode: 'back',
      },
      depthStencil: {
        depthWriteEnabled: true,
        depthCompare: 'less',
        format: 'depth24plus',
      },
      multisample: {
        count: canvasInfo.sampleCount,
      },
    });


    const vUniformBufferSize = 2 * 16 * 4; // 2 mat4s * 16 floats per mat * 4 bytes per float
    const fUniformBufferSize = 3 * 4 + 4;  // 1 vec3 * 3 floats per vec3 * 4 bytes per float + pad

    const vsUniformBuffer = device.createBuffer({
      size: vUniformBufferSize,
      usage: GPUBufferUsage.UNIFORM | GPUBufferUsage.COPY_DST,
    });
    const fsUniformBuffer = device.createBuffer({
      size: fUniformBufferSize,
      usage: GPUBufferUsage.UNIFORM | GPUBufferUsage.COPY_DST,
    });
    const vsUniformValues = new Float32Array(vUniformBufferSize / 4); // 2 mat4s
    const worldViewProjection = vsUniformValues.subarray(0, 16);
    const worldInverseTranspose = vsUniformValues.subarray(16, 32);
    const fsUniformValues = new Float32Array(fUniformBufferSize / 4);  // 1 vec3
    const lightDirection = fsUniformValues.subarray(0, 3);

    const bindGroup = device.createBindGroup({
      layout: pipeline.getBindGroupLayout(0),
      entries: [
        { binding: 0, resource: { buffer: vsUniformBuffer } },
        { binding: 1, resource: { buffer: fsUniformBuffer } },
        { binding: 2, resource: sampler },
        { binding: 3, resource: tex.createView() },
      ],
    });

    const renderPassDescriptor = {
      colorAttachments: [
        {
          // view: undefined, // Assigned later
          // resolveTarget: undefined, // Assigned Later
          clearValue: { r: 0.5, g: 0.5, b: 0.5, a: 1.0 },
          loadOp: 'clear',
          storeOp: 'store',
        },
      ],
      depthStencilAttachment: {
        // view: undefined,  // Assigned later
        depthClearValue: 1.0,
        depthLoadOp: 'clear',
        depthStoreOp: 'store',
      },
    };

    return {
      pipeline,
      bindGroup,
      renderPassDescriptor,
      vsUniformBuffer,
      fsUniformBuffer,
      vsUniformValues,
      worldViewProjection,
      worldInverseTranspose,
      fsUniformValues,
      lightDirection,
    };
  }



  function resizeToDisplaySize(device, canvasInfo) {
    const {
      canvas,
      context,
      renderTarget,
      presentationSize,
      presentationFormat,
      depthTexture,
      sampleCount,
    } = canvasInfo;
    const width = Math.min(device.limits.maxTextureDimension2D, canvas.clientWidth);
    const height = Math.min(device.limits.maxTextureDimension2D, canvas.clientHeight);

    const needResize = !canvasInfo.renderTarget ||
                       width !== presentationSize[0] ||
                       height !== presentationSize[1];
    if (needResize) {
      if (renderTarget) {
        renderTarget.destroy();
      }
      if (depthTexture) {
        depthTexture.destroy();
      }

      canvas.width = width;
      canvas.height = height;
      presentationSize[0] = width;
      presentationSize[1] = height;

      const newRenderTarget = device.createTexture({
        size: presentationSize,
        format: presentationFormat,
        sampleCount,
        usage: GPUTextureUsage.RENDER_ATTACHMENT,
      });
      canvasInfo.renderTarget = newRenderTarget;
      canvasInfo.renderTargetView = newRenderTarget.createView();

      const newDepthTexture = device.createTexture({
        size: presentationSize,
        format: 'depth24plus',
        sampleCount,
        usage: GPUTextureUsage.RENDER_ATTACHMENT,
      });
      canvasInfo.depthTexture = newDepthTexture;
      canvasInfo.depthTextureView = newDepthTexture.createView();
    }
    return needResize;
  }

  const p1 = createPipelineAndStuff(device);
  const p2 = createPipelineAndStuff(device);

  function drawPipeline(device, commandEncoder, {
      pipeline,
      bindGroup,
      renderPassDescriptor,
      vsUniformBuffer,
      fsUniformBuffer,
      vsUniformValues,
      worldViewProjection,
      worldInverseTranspose,
      fsUniformValues,
      lightDirection,
    }, { time, x, resolve, clear }) {

    const projection = mat4.perspective(30 * Math.PI / 180, canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight, 0.5, 20);
    const eye = [0, 4, 10];
    const target = [0, 0, 0];
    const up = [0, 1, 0];

    const view = mat4.lookAt(eye, target, up);
    const viewProjection = mat4.multiply(projection, view);
    const world = mat4.translation([x, 0, 0]);
    mat4.rotateY(world, time, world);
    mat4.rotateX(world, time * 0.1 + x, world);
    mat4.transpose(mat4.inverse(world), worldInverseTranspose);
    mat4.multiply(viewProjection, world, worldViewProjection);

    vec3.normalize([1, 8, 10], lightDirection);

    device.queue.writeBuffer(vsUniformBuffer, 0, vsUniformValues);
    device.queue.writeBuffer(fsUniformBuffer, 0, fsUniformValues);

    renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].loadOp = clear ? 'clear' : 'load';
    renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].view = canvasInfo.renderTargetView;
    renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].resolveTarget = resolve
        ? context.getCurrentTexture().createView()
        : undefined;
    renderPassDescriptor.depthStencilAttachment.view = canvasInfo.depthTextureView;
    renderPassDescriptor.depthStencilAttachment.depthLoadOp = clear ? 'clear' : 'load';

    const passEncoder = commandEncoder.beginRenderPass(renderPassDescriptor);
    passEncoder.setPipeline(pipeline);
    passEncoder.setBindGroup(0, bindGroup);
    passEncoder.setVertexBuffer(0, positionBuffer);
    passEncoder.setVertexBuffer(1, normalBuffer);
    passEncoder.setVertexBuffer(2, texcoordBuffer);
    passEncoder.setIndexBuffer(indicesBuffer, 'uint16');
    passEncoder.drawIndexed(indices.length);
    passEncoder.end();
  }

  function render(time) {
    time *= 0.001;
    resizeToDisplaySize(device, canvasInfo);

    const commandEncoder = device.createCommandEncoder();

    drawPipeline(device, commandEncoder, p1, { time, x: -1., resolve: false, clear: true  });
    drawPipeline(device, commandEncoder, p2, { time, x:  1., resolve: true , clear: false });

    device.queue.submit([commandEncoder.finish()]);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

function fail(msg) {
  const elem = document.querySelector('#fail');
  const contentElem = elem.querySelector('.content');
  elem.style.display = '';
  contentElem.textContent = msg;
}

main();
  
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!I tried to set loadOp to 'load' before, however, my project also contains mouse event(wheel or drag the canvas to move the map), when loadOp== 'load', the layers draw before cannot be cleared ,and more and more lines , points will remain on the screen , only loadOp=='clear' can work,I dont know how to resolve this problem. TAT

Comment: Also, the mouseevent func in my project is to use mouse XY changes to modify the mvp matrix. All the calculate proccesses of mvpmatrix are completed with compute pipeline

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Do you want to clear on a mouse event or you don't? If you do, set `loadOp: 'clear'`, if you don't, set `loadOp: load`. As for the resolve, you can do that in a separate step any time, just make a simple renderpass with the resolveTarget set and do nothing in it. So, anytime you want to see the results, do the resolve. You might find [this](https://github.com/gfxfundamentals/webgpufundamentals/discussions/44) helpful

Comment: thx for your advice！I tried to use only one depthtexture and multitexture, and it works!