# Trying to use MSAA with textures

Tags: webgpu

I'd like to use multisample anti-aliasing (MSAA) with my texture, but it's not working. When I create the texture, I set `sampleCount` to 4:

```
const texture = device.createTexture({
    size: [imageBitmap.width, imageBitmap.height],
    format: 'rgba8unorm',
    sampleCount: 4,
    usage:
         GPUTextureUsage.RENDER_ATTACHMENT |
         GPUTextureUsage.TEXTURE_BINDING |
         GPUTextureUsage.COPY_DST
});
```

The WGSL documentation says multisampled textures can't be read with samplers, so the fragment shader uses `textureLoad` instead of `textureSample`:

```
@group(0) @binding(1) var tex : texture_multisampled_2d<f32>;

@fragment
fn fragmentMain(fragData: DataStruct) -> @location(0) vec4f {
    return textureLoad(tex, fragData.uvPos, 0);
}
```

When I run the application, I'm told "no matching call to textureLoad(texture_multisampled_2d, vec2, abstract-int)". Any ideas? Are there any examples that use MSAA textures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't show the definition of `DataStruct` but my guess is `DataStruct.uvPos` is not a compatible type.

`textureLoad` takes an integer texel coordinate, not a floating point normalized texture coordinate like `textureSample`

From the spec

> `C` is `i32`, or `u32`
> `S` is `i32`, or `u32`
> `ST` is `i32`, `u32`, or `f32`
>
> ```
> fn textureLoad(t: texture_multisampled_2d<ST>,
>                coords: vec2<C>,
>                sample_index: S)-> vec4<ST>
> ```

Notice above, `C`, is only `i32` or `u32`, not `f32`

Otherwise, what are you trying to use MSAA textures for? The most common usage is for anti-aliasing but in that case you never read the texture directly. You just set it as a render target and set a non-MSAA texture as the resolve target like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77041737/128511)