# how to disable antialiasing for webgpu

Tags: html5-canvas, webgpu

`Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'antialiasing' does not exist in type 'GPUCanvasConfiguration'.ts(2353)`

But then how do I disable anti aliasing?

Comment: What's the minimal code that causes this error? What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't. webgpu does not have any kind on auto antialiasing like webgl.

In WebGPU if you want antialiasing like webgl you have to do it manually by creating your own multisampled texture, rendering to it, and resolving it to the canvas. You can see an example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77041737/128511)

by default, webgpu does not antialias

You might find [this article](https://webgpufundamentals.org/webgpu/lessons/webgpu-from-webgl.html) helpful if you're new to WebGPU and already familiar with WebGL

Answer (score 0):

As explained in https://toji.dev/webgpu-best-practices/webgl-performance-comparison#antialiasing, in WebGL, if you don’t explicitly specify otherwise the default framebuffer will be antialiased. In contrast, the textures provided by a WebGPU canvas context are always single sampled.

https://developer.chrome.com/blog/from-webgl-to-webgpu#canvas_handling is also a nice resource to learn some tips for WebGL developers who are migrating to WebGPU.

Moreover you can see in WebGPU types (https://github.com/gpuweb/types/blob/b71895f2ec6bf2cafc9d7f3fb94a9edc004f5f61/dist/index.d.ts#L600) that GPUCanvasConfiguration does not indeed contain `antialiasing`